# How to make Facebook app Live from http://localhost/index.php

Tags: php, facebook, apache

I have written a app in PHP on my localhost server using XAMP, which is meant to be a Facebook app. The app [which i wrote] consists of two php pages.

But the problem is I am not being able to make it live on Facebook. I have tried reading the documentations, but all in vain. Moreover i dont have any websites in my name.

So please kindly help, what changes should i make in my codes and the subsequent steps in making my small facebook app go online ??

Comment: This link may help you: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Buy a domain (Cheap ones are available from GoDaddy.com)
2. Buy a hosting package (also available at GoDaddy.com)
3. Wait for the DNS settings to propagate (tick-tock...could take 24 hours)
4. FTP files your your hosting plan's server
5. Change your facebook app settings to point this new domain
6. Reap the rewards of a well-written application.

Answer (score 1):

you can always get a dynamic domain like http://www.no-ip.com/  it will then allow you to setup a DNS record from them to your server / app.

The DNS would look something like **myapp.no-ip.com** (or anything else they offer).

Localhost is fine for a 'local' test, but beyond that you need to have a real way for users to reach you, remember in most cases facebook has to reach your app for confirmation, etc;.

Comment: thank you !! But what about the Heroku cloud applications Facebook is using. Heroku is providing url. Initially it works fine according to the documentation but again the problem goes with the localhost

Comment: there are many answers to your question, you basically need a stable server and a domain name to access it.